# function which converts char into integer and returns the value [C]

Tags: c, char, integer

So I was trying to write a function in C which converts a variable of `int` to `char`. While looking at previous threads I notice that the best way to so is to use it like this: `a + '0'`.

So I did:

```
char intToChar(int a) {
   return a + '0';
}
```

Although, my IDE (Clion) warns me:

> Returning 'int' from a function returning 'char': Value of type 'int' may not fit into the receiver type 'char'

So I tried to change it into the following function (replace `char` with `int`):

```
int intToChar(int a) {
    return a + '0';
}
```

And the warning disappears. But it made me wonder if it's the right way to do so. I know that when function returns `char` it actually returns `int`. But the name of the function is `intToChar` so it supposed to return `char`. Is it the right way to do so?

Comment: Your title and your code seem to concern opposite direction of conversion.

Comment: What do you want to happen in case of e.g. a value of 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to *implicit promotion rules*. In your example:

```
a + '0'
```

You are adding an `int` and a `char`. Since they are different, one of those two must be converted to the other. Since `char` is usually 8 bits and integers usually 32 (in C it is not always the case, but for the point it does not matter), what is executed is in fact:

```
a + (int)'0'
```

Long story short, the result will be an `int`. To remove this warning, just do:

```
(char) (a + '0') // or (char)a + '0'
```

*Note*: for your usecase, you could simply do `(char)a` and the result would be correct.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: good. Please, don't forget to mark the question as answered (checkmark on the left)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method of typecast but you should enter the ascii value of no for example in this case ascii value of 2 is 50.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char intToChar(int a){

    char c=(char)a;
    return c;
}

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here

    int a=50;
    char c;
    c=intToChar(50);
    printf("%c",c);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Character literal `0` is - as every character literal - of type `int` (try, for example, to print `sizeof('0')`:

```
int main() {
    printf("sizeof '0' is ... %ld\n",sizeof('0'));
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof '0' is ... 4
```

So an expression like `a + '0'` will give an `int` as well. Returning then an `int` where the function defines a return type `char` leads to this warning.

So actually you'd write `int intToChar(int a)` as you proposed, and other character based functions like `tolower` act similarly.

BTW: Note that datatype `char` is different from datatype `int`, since `char` is always guaranteed to be of size 1 by definition.

And note: when you have a `char x = 5;`, then an expression like `x + '0'` will give `int` datatype as well because `'0'` is of type `int`.